# How to get other store language

Tags: magento-1.9, language

How to use this below code to show other store language?

```
$store_language = $this->getChildHtml('store_language');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure not sure 100% about your question.

May be your **want to call language dropdown at any phtml** at frontend by `$this->getChildHtml('store_language').`

And code may be not works calling `phtml's block` class is **not  parent block of store_language block class.**

If you want to call any where at frontend area then you  try this

```
echo $store_language = $this->getBlockHtml('store_language');
```

**or call store language by create block:**

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/switch"')->setTemplate('page/switch/languages.phtm')->toHtml();
```